# Kafka consumer group does not exist while trying to retrieve detail about group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to describe the kafka consumer group via the below command in terminal:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $IP:$PORT --describe --group $GROUPID
```

I'm able to get the `$GROUPID` via this command:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $IP:$PORT --list
```

and the response is:

```
b'TestProcess'
```

But after trying to get the detail about this group via this command:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $IP:$PORT --describe --group TestProcess
```

this result will come up:

```
Error: Consumer group 'TestProcess' does not exist.
```

Kafka Version: 2.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your consumer group is named literally `b'TestProcess'`, so try issuing describe command like this:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $IP:$PORT --describe --group "b'TestProcess'"
```